# VS Code tasks.json and launch.json to launch a debug job after a preLaunchTask not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging

So I have a launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Djangp: Remote Attach",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "preLaunchTask": "up-debug",
      "connect": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 5678
      },
      "django": true,
      "justMyCode": false,
    },
]
```

and my tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "up-debug",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "make up-debug",
      // "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "custom",
        "severity": "warning",
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^\\s*(\\S+).+(celery@\\S+).+(ready)\\s*$",
          "message": 0,
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that when I start Debug, the task (make command then run docker-compose command) is running well, but the Deubg session won't start even if the docker-compose command finished with like text 'celery is redy'.
it looks like the Debug cannot find and match the text even if it is there.

What's wong with my setuo? thanks!